# Error term for a rational function approximation to $x^y=y^x$

Tags: approximation

Define a function $\mathscr E(x)$ on the interval $(e,\infty)$ implicitly via $$y=\mathscr E(x)~\Leftrightarrow~x^y=y^x,\quad x\neq y.$$
Show that $\frac{x+2}{x-1}$ approximates $\mathscr E(x)$ to an accuracy of $<0.05~$ for all $~x>e$.

The transcendental nature of $\mathscr E$ is the only thing that has this problem seemingly out of my reach; if a hint is all I may need please just drop one of those! I don't remember exactly how I originally got the value $0.05$, but I did so (clumsily) using Desmos' graphing calculator.

Comment: I played with this years ago and found a parameterization for $x$ and $y$ in terms of one variable, but cannot recover it.  I believe I made the guess that we could write $x=a^b,y=b^a$, so the equation becomes $(a^b)^{(b^a)}=(b^a)^{(a^b)}$ or $a^{b^{a+1}}=b^{a^{b+1}}$ and found $a$ and $b$ could be rational functions of the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

For the given error, you may be able to just compute.  Define $\mathscr F(x) = \mathscr E^{-1}(x)$.  We can find $\mathscr F(1.05) \approx 99, \mathscr F(1.1) \approx 43.5$  Then for $x \gt 99, 1 \lt \mathscr E(x) \lt 1.05, 1 \lt \frac {x+2}{x-1}=1+\frac 3{x-1}\lt 1.030303\ldots$ and the inequality is satisfied.  Compute $\mathscr F(x)$ on steps of $0.025$ from $1.05$ up to $e$ and verify that the two expressions are close.